# Добавление иконки к меню

Tags: c#, winforms

Для кнопки, например, просто создается ImageList, туда закидываются файлы, потом в свойствах кнопки указываем нужный ImageList и индекс иконки. Для MenuStrip в инспекторе свойств вообще нет поля ImageList. Попытался руками назначить в конструкторе - ничего толкового не вышло. Добавлял картинку в ресурсы - тоже ничего. Подскажите что я не так делаю? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще простейший способ добавить к пункту меню иконку - добавить ее в *Resources.resx* и проставить ее в свойстве *Image* вашего пункта. Если вы все-таки намерены использовать ImageList, то можно воспользоваться, например, таким кодом в конструкторе:

```
for (int i = 0; i < menuStrip1.Items.Count; i++)
{
  menuStrip1.Items[i].Image = imageList1.Images[i];
}
```